# jQuery Validation displays errors as inline by default, need to change this to inline-block

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

How do I change the generated error messages `display` value to `inline-block` when not hidden?

I have tried with CSS but the jQuery overwrites this.

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you done so far?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this is a an internal project so I can't direct you to a link. I'm trying to find where the jquery tells the code to add display:inline to the error label when displayed, and change that to display:inline-block

Comment: I did not ask you to post a link.  None the less, simply look inside the plugin and customize as needed... it's just jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: I have, I've searched but cannot find it, that's why I'm here

Comment: I appreciate that, but the fact that you've already looked at customizing the plugin's code should have also been mentioned in your question.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it next time, cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `errorClass` option to specify the class assigned to error messages and error elements:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   errorClass: "invalid"
})

<style type="text/css">
  .invalid {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
</style>
```

See the documentation for validator options:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Comment: With this, it's impossible for the errors to be hidden once the field is valid

Comment: Agreed with @jetlej, This breaks validation functionality as the display:none generated by the plugin to hide the unneeded validation error message is no longer heeded due to the !important.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this and couldn't use CSS as jQuery is using the show() and hide() methods on the error element (which set "display:block;" inline) after initial creation.  Instead you can use the validate plugin's highlight and unhighlight methods to change the inline css.

```
    errorElement: 'em',

highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass); // good for changing field backgrounds
    $(element).next('em').css('display','inline'); // keeps error message layout clean
},

unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass); // good for changing field backgrounds
        $(element).next('em').css('display','none'); // keeps error message layout clean
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `!important` on your CSS, it should take precedence over what jQuery does:

```
.error {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, works for me... Have you looked in Firebug, or another debugger to see what style is applied and what is causing the `inline-block` to not be applied?

Comment: The inline styling from the plugin overwrites the CSS

Comment: I don't see any inline style applied by plugin. Only <label class="error"> gets added

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validate does not have any CSS styles defined. Are you using any other libraries with CSS definitions for "error" class?

Here is JsFiddle sample code with jQuery validate using inline-block for error message:

http://jsfiddle.net/maxim75/HKnQD/4/

```
.error
{
    color: Red;
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

Open it up and check in your browser:

[image]